# How "value" prop in v-tabs and v-tab-item controls visibility?

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

From Vuetify documentation (https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/tabs) on v-tabs component it says that "value" property "Controls visibility".
In which way it controls visibility? 
When I try to set this prop to false I get infinite loop and browser hangs.
I don't understand how this prop works but I see it used in Vuetify official examples where it's set to string.

Answer (score 1):

In this case, the value controls which tab is currently selected. You bind that value using the `v-model` property. To show and hide the tabs you can simply use a `v-if`.

Comment: I thought currently active tab is selected with v-model on v-tabs component, based on this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50392918/vuetify-how-to-preselect-active-tab

Comment: Yes and the `v-model` is just shorthand for binding to the `value` prop and subscribing to the `input` event.