# How to set Vuetify tabs to active based on url

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuetify.js, vuetify-tabs

I'm using `vue 2.6.11`, `vuetify 2.2.9` and [`ziggy 0.8.1`](https://github.com/tightenco/ziggy). 
For the Vuetify tabs I have the following:

```
<template>
    <v-tabs
        background-color="transparent"
        slider-color="secondary"
        icons-and-text
        dark
        :value="`${route().current()}`"
        v-model="active_tab"
    >
        <v-tab
            :href="route('project.projects.show', $page.project.id)"
            link
            exact
            key="project.projects.show"
        >
            Project
        </v-tab>

        <v-tab
            :href="route('project.projects.company', $page.project.id)"
            link
            exact
            key="project.projects.company"
        >
            Company
        </v-tab>

        <v-tab
            :href="route('project.invoices.index', $page.project.id)"
            link
            exact
            key="'project.invoices.index"
        >
            Invoices
        </v-tab>
    </v-tabs>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    data()
    {
        return {
            active_tab: `${route().current()}`,
        }
    },
}
</script>
```

Depending on the location of `route().current()` it returns a different value. In the `<template>` it returns the full URL and in the `<script>` it only returns the Laravel route name. The problem is even though the key and `route().current()` match, the corresponding tab still isn't set to active.

Have looked at [Vuetify: How to preselect active tab?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50392918/vuetify-how-to-preselect-active-tab) but none of the answers work.

**Update**

After looking at it some more it turns out that `` active_tab: `${route().current()}`, `` is always set to wrong URL. For example when on the invoices route it still returns the url for the project. So it is related to ziggy.

Comment: Have you tried to use a computed property for `active_tab` ?

Comment: @IVOGELOV tried it but doesn't work either. But what would it add compared to setting it directly or during `mounted()`?

Comment: @IVOGELOV have updated the question with some more details

Comment: You can try to use Vue-router - it should be more robust than `ziggy`

Comment: @IVOGELOV I'm using Ziggy because I'm also using inertiajs which make security a lot easier.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Looks like that setting the `v-model` attribute of `v-tabs` equal to `window.location.href` in the `data` object solves it.

Answer (score 1):

```
<v-tabs :value="tab_value_in_url">
   <v-tab :to="/pages/tab1">Tab 1</v-tab>
</v-tabs>

<v-tabs-items v-model="tab_value_in_url">
      <v-tab-item value="tab1">...</v-tab-item>
</v-tabs-items>
```

The important parts are:

- set `:value` on `<v-tabs>` to some computed property that returns the tab ID (`tab1` in this example`)
- set `:to` on each tab to redirect when clicked
- set `v-model` on `<v-tabs-items>` to point to the same `:value` on `<v-tabs>`
- set `value` on `<v-tab-item>` to each tab ID (`tab1` in this example)